# How to redirect a page to a heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku, mean-stack

I'm fairly new to node.js and I've pushed an app to heroku whhich adress would look like this `https://someapp.heroku.com`

Now, I would like to redirect my website to this app in heroku but not the domain itself, meaning, I would like to redirect `http://www.domain.com/login` to `https://someapp.heroku.com` and not `http://www.domain.com` to the app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manage domains for an app in Dashboard, go to its “Settings” tab. Heroku provides neither domain registration service (for registering a custom domain name) nor DNS provider service (for hosting the DNS servers that point your custom domain name at your app)

refrence link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand that heroku does not provide domains nor dns provider service. I already have a domain purchased somewhere else but I need to redirect for instance domain.com/something to [myapp].herokuapp.com instead of domain.com to [myapp].herokuapp.com.